# Can I ask to start part-time when the position is full-time and go full-time later?

Tags: part-time, anxiety

My girlfriend had to quit her last full-time job due to severe anxiety and burn-out. After taking some time off and taking therapy, she feels ready to start working again, preferably part-time (4/5 days, in Belgium).

She applied for an administrative job, thinking that the application would take at least a month longer. But they told her she could start next week. She forgot to ask for part-time possibilities because she was nervous.

She has an introduction first day on Monday. Is it ok to ask them if she can start part-time until she feels more confident to take on a heavier workload?

If yes, how would she go about asking this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Is parttime common in your country and industry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the job terms and conditions should be agreed upon and communicated before starting the job.

Its quite ok to talk to the HR directly over phone perhaps or meeting in person to talk about this and if a verbal agreement is reached then she can ask for an updated job offer. This in person or phone call conversation is more important in my view instead of an email etc. Because it gives the opportunity to convey the proper message in 2 way communication right on spot.

In case they accept her request or not she will be well positioned right there to take the decision and convey her final acceptance for the offer made.

I had personally successfully negotiated to make a full time job as a part time over a phone conversation. But it also depends on the nature of job and business. That is whether its possible to offer a part time role or a full time role is required instead.